# How much bigger could Earth be, before rockets wouldn't work?

Tags: launch, rockets, payload, escape-velocity, performance

**hint:** *Apparently the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation* does not actually say *that you can launch a conventional rocket into orbit around an arbitrarily large and massive body.*

I'm looking for a number based on scaling the earth radius and maintaining the same average density. Must attain LEO, *which also gets faster* as the planet grows. Don Pettit's [Tyranny](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/expeditions/expedition30/tryanny.html) mentioned in [this nice answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17426/12102) is fun, but does not present enough math.

On *this* Earth, rockets barely work. Payloads can only be a few percent of the total mass for [LEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit), and less than one percent for deep space.

If we define slightly heavier Earths, say Earth<sub>1.1</sub>, Earth<sub>1.2</sub>... where the radii were 1.1, 1.2, etc. times that of Earth and the masses were 1.1<sup>3</sup>, 1.2<sup>3</sup>, etc. times the Earth's mass (in other words same average density, same "iron/rock ratio") what happens? Is there some point where chemical rockets simply will no longer be able to put things in space, or does the payload mass simply become ridiculously tiny? If there is a cut-off, is it different for LEO and deep space?

For our purposes, let's not explore alternative or hybrid launch systems or boost systems (such as balloons, planes, laser beams, space elevators etc.). Just stick to chemical propellant rockets.

**edit:** here is a guide. So for a scaling factor $f$:

$$
r = f r_{earth}
$$
$$
m = f^3 m_{earth}
$$
$$
g = G \frac{m}{r^2} = \frac{f^3}{f^2}g_{earth} = f g_{earth}
$$
$$
H = \frac{kT}{gm_{molecule}} = f^{-1}H_{earth}
$$

We catch a little break here. Assuming same surface atmosphere composition, temperature and pressure (STP), the [scale height](http://spacemath.gsfc.nasa.gov/astrob/7Page15.pdf) H actually *decreases* with increasing $f$. (If we were "world builders" we should probably increase pressure to get more oxygen needed for moving in the higher gravity, but that's [a different Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).)

As far as LEO **altitude** is concerned (thanks @Lex for [catching](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14383/how-much-bigger-could-earth-be-before-rockets-wouldt-work?noredirect=1#comment73460_14383) that) one might define it as the same number of scale heights as would be on Earth. That's not really so useful because the density profiles of the bits of the atmosphere responsible for drag ([Thermosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermosphere) and [Exosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exosphere) are affected by many phenomenon, including the solar wind, and don't scale at all like the lower layers. Nonetheless for historical reasons I'll leave the following, as it is not essential to the question:

$$
h_{LEO} = h_{LEOearth} \frac{H}{H_{earth}} = f^{-1} h_{LEOearth}
$$
$$
v_{LEO}=fv_{LEOearth}
$$

The LEO period is independent of the size of a planet, if the average density is fixed. However, the velocity of LEO *does* scale with radius!

Comment: Related: [On a Super-Earth 1.5x the volume and mass of Earth, would our rocket technology allow us to reach orbit?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/5320/4660). Look at Russell Borogove's answer at the bottom.

Comment: @kimholder I looked and the scaling is all jumbled up in the text and not clear to me. But since the surface gravity only increase by 14.5%, *that* earth is made of swiss cheese. In my question I ask that the average density be the same. So if the radius is 1.1 times earth radius, then the mass is (1.1)^3 times the earth mass.

Comment: True, but the main thing was that, in theory, any gravity can be overcome if you put enough stages in your humongous rocket. So then the question turns into a matter of what is practical. I don't know if there is a way to define the question to put a useful limit on that. The limits of structural materials? The GDP of the planet? Not being facetious, btw.

Comment: Can we see "the main thing" as an equation, not a slogan?  If the answer is that there is no limit, then let's just get it out there in math rather than paragraphs.

Comment: What i said applies to the equation. Earth could be the size of Jupiter (but like Earth), and it would still be possible to launch a rocket from it - as long as that rocket had enough stages. The payload fraction approaches zero, but doesn't reach it.

Comment: I understand that in free space, the final velocity (delta-v) is limitless. See [this answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/13767/12102). But is it really true when accelerating in the gravity field of a planet? No matter how strong the gravity, a chemical rocket can produce enough thrust to counter it all the way to orbit? If this is *known to be true*, then it must have been calculated and proven. This is rocket science, not rocket folklore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36748/discussion-between-kim-holder-and-uhoh).

Comment: I still think the issue is what point we will assign as being the boundary of 'ridiculous'. Say, if there was a beautiful garden world that was a moon of this planet, maybe they would expend extraordinary effort to get just one rocket there.

Comment: @kimholder I know, I am sure there are other ways to get off the planet. Maybe it's like Apollo plus CERN plus the Human Genome Project just to get a cubesat suborbital, but it would happen. **This question** however is about conventional, chemical rockets, and it's really a math problem with that constraint. There's a number, probably between 1 and 2, and Don Petit suggests it's around 1.5 but with unclear constraints. I'm just after the correct answer with the math or a reproducible calculation - like a Kerbal YouTube or something.

Comment: Yeah, but that is the thing - as i understand it, there is no such number, theoretically. Any number of stages can be placed on a rocket, and each one increases the gravity that can be overcome - by ever smaller amounts, but that amount is never zero. I suppose there is a point where the amount is so small it is less than the variance introduced by wind and temperature and such... maybe that could be a limit...

Comment: @kimholder If so, I need to see the math then. Not just a classic equation, but someone needs to work the problem and if what you are saying is true, make a plot (for example) of total rocket mass to put say 10kg in some kind of LEO as a function of planet_radius / earth_radius. An abstract, simplified detla-v is not sufficient for this question. If launching in air, and turning in gravity, and attaining orbital velocity is actually possible for arbitrarily large, same-density earths, this should be demonstrable with math.

Comment: Uhoh, i have begun a bounty on your behalf. This is the most effective way to improve odds of getting the information you seek. It would be a good idea for you to also withdraw your acceptance of the current answer, as that gives the immediate impression that there is no need for further answers.

Comment: @kimholder wow! OK that's great, thank you very much for your help and interest!

Comment: The r_LEO calculation is wrong. Scale height is a distance above the surface not from the planets center, so a ratio of scale heights would not equal a ratio of radii. The fact that the current formula is wrong is obvious since for large enough f, it says r_LEO is within the planet.

Comment: @Lex oh! I see what you mean. Indeed, those should be altitudes. Okay I'll fix that. Thanks! **edit:** how that it look now?

Comment: @uhoh, This change should effect the rest of the conclusions about LEO, but as far as I can tell those don't follow from the incorrect r_LEO calculation anyways. The other conclusions are actually correct under the simpler assumption that h_LEO<<r thus r~r_LEO.

Comment: @Lex knowing that someone has actually read one of my questions through to the end makes my day!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On a Super-Earth 1.5x the volume and mass of Earth, would our rocket technology allow us to reach orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/on-a-super-earth-1-5x-the-volume-and-mass-of-earth-would-our-rocket-technology)

Comment: @RoryAlsop That question's OP  has already voted for that question to be marked as duplicate of this one. It has three close votes already in the last few hours. https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5320/#comment78283_5320 That question's OP also added a bounty to this question a while ago to help make sure this also received an answer. Beyond that, there is no answer to this question there.

Comment: I'd suggest closing as dupe of the original one and merging.

Comment: That's absolutely fine. Anyone can vote the way they like. I'd rather do it without getting multiple comments every time I do something. Like I said, it's really annoying and does nothing to help. Please stop it.

Comment: I wasn't sure you knew the other question was closer to closing. Just trying to help.

Comment: @uhoh , just a nit, but postulating a constant mass density as radius increases means *you're changing the planet's composition*! We typically regard liquids and solids as "incompressible", but at the huge pressures in Earth's interior even iron's density increases from 7874 kg/m^3 to ~13000 kg/m^3. Scientists modeling planetary interiors have to consider "compressed density". If you increase a planet's radius without changing its composition, interior pressures increase and the average density increases. Growing while maintaining density requires higher fractions of the lighter constituents.

Comment: @TomSpilker I specified *same density profile* and same average density as Earth to keep the problem simple enough that someone might actually take the time to answer. Asking people to find the compressibility for each strata at some assumed temperature profile, and then solving for the density profile would result in zero answers.

Comment: @uhoh , Second sentence after **Question:** is "I'm looking for a number with backup, based on scaling the earth radius and *maintaining the same average density*."

Comment: @TomSpilker the same density profile (say 1.5 at the surface to 15 in the center) would result in the same average density. It doesn't mean the density would be constant.

Comment: @uhoh , yep, it's beyond what a lot of people would be willing to tackle. That's why I say it's a "nit". But I find that phenomenon very interesting in the way it must be included when doing interior models.

Comment: @uhoh , "the same density profile (say 1.5 at the surface to 15 in the center)," Yes, that's what I assumed you meant, and it's a perfectly good postulate. It's just not what actually happens. If we want to continue this we should probably move to chat. I've never done that before, have you?

Comment: If you see a message inviting you, you can activate it. It will create a new chat room for us and include copies of our recent activity. Sure, go for it! Or we can just start chatting in the [Pod Bay](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77220/discussion-between-tom-spilker-and-uhoh).

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune your edits are always welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Because linear increases in delta-v require exponential increases in mass, small changes to the assumptions you make about fuel tank structural mass and engine thrust-to-weight ratio start to make very large changes in the final size of the rocket.

For example, if you're getting off a 3.6g planet with a 7-stage rocket, the difference between 88% fuel fraction and 92% fuel fraction yields about a 10:1 difference in the total mass of the rocket.

So I don't think it's really reasonable to talk about ultimate theoretical limits; too many engineering factors are involved.

Locking down a lot of variables, I can tell you what kind of rocket you'd need for a given surface g, though. Let's make these assumptions:

- We are placing 1 ton of payload into low planetary orbit.
- Required delta-v to reach orbit, including atmospheric and gravity losses, is 10,000m/s per surface g. Seems to hold for Earth, Mars, and the "Earthtoo" which was discussed [in another Q/A](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17457/can-planet-earthtoo-put-a-tooian-in-orbit-too/17459#17459).
- We can build rocket stages of arbitrary size, with a tankage propellant fraction of 90%; the rocket stage mass is the tank mass plus the engine mass -- ullage rockets, interstage, etc. is all handwaved out.
- We have an infinite supply of Apollo-era rocket engines: RL-10, J-2, M-1, H-1, and F-1.
- First-stage TWR at ignition must be at least 1.2 (relative to local gravity)
- Middle-stage TWR at ignition must be at least 0.8
- Final-stage TWR at ignition must be at least 0.5

Given those assumptions, here is a table of surface gravity, stage count, first-stage engines, and total rocket mass.

```
Surface                         First        Total       Saturn V 
Gravity   Stages                Stage      Mass, t     Equivalent
 0.5           2             1x RL-10          4.5
 1.0           3             1x   H-1         49.4          0.02
 1.5           3             1x   F-1        249.2           0.1
 2.0           4             5x   F-1       1329.0           0.5
 2.5           5            40x   F-1       8500.9             3
 3.0           6           274x   F-1      50722.2            17
 3.5           7          2069x   F-1     331430.9           100
 4.0           8         20422x   F-1    2836598.4           950
 4.5           8        392098x   F-1   47 million         15000
 5.0           9    3.5 million   F-1  391 million        130000
 6.0          11    400 million   F-1   38 billion      millions
10.0          18        2.88e19   F-1      1.65e21  quadrillions
```

Up above 10g, something really interesting happens that is kind of a theoretical limit. The mass of the rocket reaches *a measurable fraction of the mass of the entire planet* it's launching from.

At 10.3g, rocket mass is 0.035 of the mass of the planet.
10.4g, rocket mass is one fifth of the mass of the planet. This doesn't actually alter the ∆v requirement -- we're going into orbit around the rocket/planet barycenter!
At 10.47g, the rocket *is* the planet, and we're... just... chewing it up entirely, pulverizing it in a dust cloud expanding at 4km/s.

These extreme conclusions appear to be corroborated by [this independently derived paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.11384.pdf), which explores some other related aspects of super-Earth-based chemical rockets.

Another consideration recently brought up by user @uhoh is that as the linear scale of a given rocket stage increases, its mass, and thus the required thrust force to lift it, goes up by the cube of the scale, but the area available at the base of the rocket to mount engines goes up only by the square of the scale; this problem is made even worse here by the increasing surface gravity. The Saturn V was just about at the point where this relation starts to become problematic; the outboard engines on its first stage are mounted at the very edge of the stage in order to make room for their nozzles to gimbal.

Solid rockets don't have the same dimensional constraints, and have very good thrust-to-weight and thrust-to-cost ratios, so they're probably more likely to be used in lower stages for these very large rockets.

Stages much larger than the Saturn V first stage would need to address this with some combination of being shorter and squatter, or compromising engine gimbal range, or mounting engines in pods surrounding the tankage, and there might be fairly hard engineering limits at some point for those reasons. At the 3g mark, for example, the 274 first-stage engines would require a stage about 90 meters in diameter and 9 meters tall, at which point the engineering inefficiencies associated with the fuel tank proportions will be becoming serious.

Comment: Awesome. I'm happy now. :)

Comment: @kimholder me too - thank you very much for your support and interest! I'm glad we go to the bottom of this.

Comment: Thanks you very much Russell Borogove for your systematic approach and persistence. We can call this *The Tyranny of the Exponential!* Very nice.

Comment: Just in the range 1.0 to 4.0 earths, rocket mass increases almost a factor of 40 for every earth mass. Yikes!

Comment: If you haven't seen it yet, @AtmosphericPrisonEscape's [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/on-a-super-earth-1-5x-the-volume-and-mass-of-earth-would-our-rocket-technology#comment78239_5320) points to a recent [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.11384) with a similar exponential increase, where the mass reaches "1 Florida" at about 9 Earth masses. You might consider adding a link to it.

Comment: From that article: "On worlds with a surface gravity of  >10g0, a sizable fraction of the planet needs to be used up as chemical fuel per launch, limiting the total number of flights" -- good corroboration!

Comment: About a month ago I downloaded specs on the SpaceX Falcon 9, and their 1st stage is getting a propellant mass fraction of nearly 94%, the 2nd stage nearly 96%! (That's total propellant, not usable propellant, so the practical numbers would be a bit less) Using these numbers would modify the results in your table, but the last couple of rows would still have – heh – astronomical numbers. Interestingly, since I downloaded that info SpaceX has taken all mass info off their Falcon 9 home page! I guess they want you to go to the User Manual.

Comment: @TomSpilker My calculator prefers hydrogen-oxygen for stages after the first, and hydrogen stages tend to have worse mass fraction than kerosene stages (due to insulation, and needing more engine volume to achieve the same thrust) but better delta-v due to higher specific impulse. I was trying to stay on the conservative side with mass fractions for my definitive answer.

Comment: @RussellBorogove , the inert mass fractions for hydrogen-oxygen stages are certainly higher. The 10% you use is pretty close to the S-IVB. Your approach is probably best.

Comment: This is like an XKCD what-if, the *everybody dies* kind. Love it.

Comment: "The planet is the rocket!" Ahaha how theoretically sound yet functionally absurd! I love it.

Comment: Would a planet with 10g gravity experience some differences in chemical reactions and/or other phenomena, which could alter not only the calculated fuel needed, but also maybe enable different reactions or physical systems which do not happen on Earth and could be used instead of how we launch rockets?

Comment: "The mass of the rocket reaches a measurable fraction of the mass of the entire planet it's launching from." Surely almost all of this mass would never leave the planet?

Comment: "Fortunately", though, given observational data thanks to observatories like Kepler, planets with masses beyond about maybe $6\ M_\oplus$ ($3.6 \times 10^{4}\ \mathrm{Yg}$) or so seem to reliably accrue and maintain a thick hydrogen envelope, which renders them unsuitable for life. As surface gravity roughly goes as the cube root of the mass for a given density/composition (here, rock), that means only up to ~1.8 gee should be encountered by virtually any alien civilization in getting off its homeworld. Nonetheless, that still looks like on the order of 1000 Mg of rocket...

Comment: That said, there is always Project Orion-like nuclear propulsion which could have much higher thrust, and thus aliens from a higher gravity (if/how it happens) world could potentially develop faster spacecraft sooner out of necessity.

Comment: A high-g planet has a much thinner atmosphere. The scale height goes as 1/g, and the number density at constant pressure goes as 1/g (each atom weighs more). So a 100km density on earth is reached at 250m altitude on a 20g planet. Maybe build a Big Rocket Accelerator Track on top of 250m towers?

Comment: @RussellBorogove but with each flight, the required rocket size decreases! Now we just need planets made out of rocket fuel (and instantly see the impetus for leaving thast place as soon as possible)

Comment: "At 10.47g, the rocket *is* the planet" - Rather, the planet is the rocket, and good news you've already reached escape velocity for *free* and entered into solar orbit.

Answer (score 32):

First, let us look at the [rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation):

$$\Delta v=\ln \left(\frac{m_0}{m_f}\right)v_e$$

That tells how much a rocket can change its velocity (the $\Delta v$). The requirements for reaching a higher velocity for a minimal orbit would increase on your heavier Earth. (For constant density it is proportional to the radius.)

How can we increase the $\Delta v$ of the rocket to keep up? We can increase the exhaust velocity, $v_e$, of the engine, but that cut-off is around 5000 m/s for chemical engines. The other thing we could do is increasing the mass ratio of the rocket $\left(\frac{m_0}{m_f}\right)$. That is problematic too, as we can not really make the fuel tanks out of soap bubbles. Staging is the option left, you could place a big rocket under a small rocket to get a little more change in velocity. Then you are getting a linear benefit for an exponential expense.

As an example, the Saturn V rocket got into LEO (~9000 m/s), sent a payload towards the Moon (3120 m/s), the service module slowed the stack into LMO (820 m/s), and finally the LM landed and took off again (2*1720 m/s). There are still some unused fuel left in the service module then, so let us just call the total $\Delta v$ of the Saturn V/Apollo 17 km/s. That is less than the requirements for a 2x radius Earth. The Apollo program was pretty expensive [citation needed], so it may take a while before a nation of a 2x Earth world attempts to go into orbit. The limit is, as you state, the ridiculously low payload ratio.

Another consideration is the increased surface gravity. (That scales linearly with diameter at constant density). That requires the rocket to have a higher thrust to weight ratio, and that will increase the dry mass, reducing the possible $\Delta v$. (It also increases gravity losses, but that is mostly compensated by the lower scale height of the planet, reducing drag losses).

Eventually, the gravity is so high that even the most powerful engine can not lift itself from the ground. That at least is a definitive limit.

**A more theoretical consideration, is $\Delta v$ requirements actually a finite limit?**

Surprisingly, it is not. Remember what I said about staging earlier: "you are getting a linear benefit for an exponential expense". But there is not limit to what we can expend! Consider the following scenario: We add more and more stages at the bottom of the rocket, each of them has the same mass as all the stages on top of it. Then burning each of them gives the same mass ratio between before and after, therefore each of them are supplying
the same amount of $\Delta v$. To add 10 times that amount, you need 10 stages each doubling the mass. To add 100 times that amount, you need to double a hundred times. The mass grows ridiculously fast, even doubling 10 times are over a thousand times more. But why should we stop :)

**But can we *really* continue to add exponentially larger stages for ever?**

After a while, other problems show up. For instance: Rockets are long and thin, to minimize drag. That shape can not be kept for very large rockets. The reason not is the [square cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-cube_law). Conserving the same dimensional proportions, a rocket twice the height has 8 times more mass. But the base area of the rocket has only increased 4 times. That means that each unit of area has to support more mass. Sooner or later, even the strongest materials must give up, and you must give up the traditional rocket shape in favour of a wider base. That adds a lot to the drag! Problems like that are going to continue to show up:

"More mass means more problems, exponentially more mass means exponentially more problems."

**Summarized:**

A modern design, larger rocket than the Saturn V, with modifications to increase the T/W ratio could probably make it to orbit on a 2x radius, 8x mass Earth. That is a feasibility limit, rockets that are ridiculously much larger may have a few km/s extra $\Delta v$, but that does not alter the numbers a lot. In theory though, rockets can grow until the drag stops them, or the engines can no longer lift even themselves.

Or perhaps you at some point want to use the available resources of the planet to launch a single rocket to orbit.

Comment: Thanks! Can you summarize as a number in the format described in the question? Are you saying that a Saturn V can give you "LEO" on an earth with *2x radius and 8x mass* (e.g. earth_2.0)?? I don't think that's going to work! I'm looking for the limits. The discussion of things to consider is great, but let's get to a single number, or possibly two - one for LEO one for "deep space".

Comment: OK, when you say "That is less than the requirements for a 2x radius Earth." can you show that using math, not words? What *are* the requirements for a 2x radius (8x mass) earth, numerically, and why does a Saturn V satisfy it? If there are design changes (T/W) how much? 10%? 10X?  Is there a chance this can be done with a simulator program or even Kerbal?

Comment: @uhoh Don't be too fast on that, especially when a bounty is involved. I agree this is a good answer, but sometimes even better answers come along. Bounties exist to stimulate that kind of interest.

Comment: I was interested by @RussellBorogove's comment in The Pod Bay about the limitations on engine T/W ratios. That seems to be something that can be given a theoretical limit if only chemical engines are considered.

Comment: @kimholder I can try to write something about that too.

Comment: @kimholder ya that was a stunning, mic-drop moment. It's possible ceramics and composites could buy a little more ratio, but ultimately you need an old fashioned pressure vessel that can take temperature and transfer the force and vibration to the rocket above.

Comment: I believe this is the wrong Tsiolkovsky rocket equation. It is indicating the maximum change in velocity you can obtain relative to some initial velocity out in deep space. It does not account for the fact that you must spend some of your momentum fighting gravity. The actual equation would have a negative term with `g` in it on the RHS, and their sum would be your actual delta V budget. The absence of this term makes it look like there's no limit on the payload you can hoist, when in fact there is. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88163/22375

Answer (score 14):

**note:** I've accepted an answer 2.5 years ago. This paper was published recently so I thought I would add this *supplemental answer* since it may be an interesting reference for future readers.

---

The Space.com article [No Way Out? Aliens on 'Super-Earth' Planets May Be Trapped by Gravity](https://www.space.com/40375-super-earth-exoplanets-hard-aliens-launch.html) links to Michael Hippke's ArXiv preprint [Spaceflight from Super-Earths is difficult](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04727).

While the calculation is based on escape velocity rather than LSEO (Low Super-Earth Orbit) the conclusion is similar, the problem is exponential and it gets really difficult quickly.

The author uses the example of the planet [Keppler-20b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler-20b) (see also [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06836)), and although there is some uncertainty, the planet's size is roughly 1.9 that of earth, and it's mass is almost 10 times that of Earth.

> For a mass ratio of 83, the minimum rocket (1 t to $v_{esc}$) would carry 9,000 t of fuel on Kepler-20b, which is 3× larger than a Saturn V (which lifted 45 t). To
>   lift a more useful payload of 6.2 t as required for the James Webb Space Telescope on Kepler-20 b, the fuel mass would increase to 55,000 t, about the mass of the largest ocean battleships. **For a classical Apollo moon mission (45 t), the rocket would need to be considerably larger, ∼ 400,000 t. This is of order the mass of the Pyramid of Cheops, and is probably a realistic limit for chemical rockets regarding cost constraints.** (emphasis added)

Comment: More stages that's all.

Comment: @Muze: I was taken aback to discover that indeed the linked paper makes no attempt to consider additional stages beyond a simplistic two-stage Falcon-9-alike. (It also makes the distressing blunder of conflating the linear mass increase from a payload increase with the exponential mass increase of a velocity increase.)

Comment: Actually, the best quote from this paper is **"On  worlds with a surface gravity of $\geq$ 10g,  a sizable fraction of the planet would need to be used up as chemical fuel per launch, limiting the total number of flights."**

Comment: "limiting the total number of flights" Unless you make your flights with escape velocity, in which case you will soon not be troubled by a high gravity any more. :)

Answer (score 9):

Not a planetological exposition in sight so, I'll add my two cents to this rather theoretical discussion.

Amongst exoplanetologists, the consensus has emerged that 1.6 Earth radii and 5 Earth masses is likely [to be the upper limit to rocky planets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4457). Simulations have shown that above these figures, the bodies develop [increasingly Mini-Neptune](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-Neptune) like characteristics. This means very thick Helium Hydrogen atmospheres and crushing surface pressure.

Also since [Michael Hippke's slightly whimsical paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04727) was referenced in one of the answers it seems appropriate to mention Ocean worlds at Super Earth masses. Ocean worlds present a host of habitability hurdles including a paucity of certain life critical elements like phosphorus, lack of volcanism, no water rock interface due to high pressure ice on the marine floor and others. These conditions will likely limit or even prevent the establishment of the vibrant prebiotic chemical environments that are necessary for biogenesis.

If the first assumption holds true, the highest gravity on a potentially  habitable world will not exceed approximately 2.5g.(edit: and thus making it not quite so difficult to reach orbit with chemical rockets as would have been the case with a higher g value)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can't guess what "increasingly Mini-Neptune like characteristics" means or what "Hippke's paper" is. Without any linked sources or cited references in your post it's hard to know what this means or judge your answer's veracity. Is it possible to support this with some links and/or citations? Thanks, and *Welcome to Space!*

Comment: Where in your answer is the question about rockets addressed?

Comment: Hi, uhoh! Thanks for the greeting. I edited for a little clarity and added a couple random expository footnotes. There are thousands of papers on these topics.

Comment: @ Organic Marble, the primary impediment to reaching orbit discussed here is high gravity. Thus, I think a comment on the likely upper limit of habitable worlds gravitational strength is warranted. As a side note greater aerodynamic forces at higher atmospheric pressures than exist on Earth also deserves attention, but as an aerospace engineer  you're likely better equipped to write about that than I am. Cheers.

Comment: @pres1dentkang you are right that this is a *comment*. It is not an *answer* and shouldn't be posted as such.

Comment: Charming. Best regards.

Comment: "1.6 Earth radii and 5 Earth masses" It seems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler-20b mentioned in another anwer is a counterexample to this, assumed to be a rocky world with 9 M⊕ and 1.9 R⊕ (still Wolfram Alpha tells me its surface gravity should be around 2.5g)

Answer (score 2):

Great answers have been given, but one of the major themes is they assume a fixed wet to dry mass ratio of 10:1 (ish). The justification is:

- You need to fix this as: there are no meaningful answers with without *a* value and, *which* value is subject to engineering nuances, which are difficult to handle.
- 10:1 is a good pick. (We can't do much better than this and still have everything work so it seems sensible to stick at this)

The problem is that's the limit of what we can make work *on earth*. A lot of the dry mass of a rocket is either:

- directly related to the thrust-to-mass ratio (i.e. number/size of engines)
- indirectly related to TMR (i.e. supports the structural loads)

Note, to keep gravity loses equivalent in practice the accelerations needed, hence TMR, is linear with the surface gravity. Hence so is a part of the the wet/dry mass ratio.

Once we take that into consideration things look a lot bleaker for the high g super-earths getting something into orbit using chemical rockets.

The actual numbers here are a little difficult to know, but if 5g world leads to a rocket with a w/d mass ratio of 5 to 1 (which I think is about right but...), you're staring down the barrel of a $10^{20}$t type figure for launch mass. To put that into perspective, the 'moon rocket' is no longer a good comparison. That's the mass of the moon it got to.

Theoretical limit? **I'd say so**.

At that mass things start taking a turn for the 'XKCD'. Forget the practical issues they're clearly long gone at "moon-sized-anything". We hit cold hard theoretical limits.
**You start having to deal with your own gravity**.

Firstly those practical issues are big ones even if we laugh a little 'engineering' problems (like money, and where we might find $10^{19}$t of aerospace grade materials). For example that's the sort of size that when you're made out something solid and are already floating in space under 0G, you deforming under you own gravity into a ball. Trying to make that out of mostly liquid fuel and subject it to 5-10g..., you're not staying the shape you started. Doesn't matter what mass-ratio 'hit' you are willing to take. But we've got this far, we aren't going to let a lack of unobtainium stop us.

No the *real* hard limit is how being so heavy effects your exhaust velocity. At the risk of getting too meta here if you're heavy enough, its difficult to get things to come apart from you. It applies to planet sized rockets as much as it does planets.

If you're a few million kilos, your 'exhaust velocity' is the velocity you can get your propellant to get to. If you have more mass than the moon, your propellant will have lost a lot of momentum by the time it's left your gravitational influence. And this is the fate our rocket meets.
LOX/H2 has an exhaust velocity of about $4,400ms^{-1}$, about as good as we can do.  Let's just say our moon-sized rocket has the density of the moon too, and so has a similar escape velocity of $2,380ms^{-1}$. Then the useful exhaust velocity of our rocket (initial less escape) is less than half. hence half the delta-v. You won't be going to space to day.

"Ok", I hear you say, "that just mean's you can't go to space in *that* rocket.", "How about a **bigger** one?". Well "No". This is another one of those "Even if everything sort of worked as before, you want go twice as fast, which is going to be a *lot* more mass." type problems. Except now we really can't just take the "make in 10 orders of magnitude bigger" approach. Apart from the fact that our rocket is now lot bigger than the planet which means we couldn't possibly construct it, now we have no chance of using chemical rockets to propel us anywhere.
To gain any momentum we need to chuck something out of our gravity well, and the exhaust velocity of chemical rockets don't make when we are this big.
We are now *truly* stuck.

But wait: directly the exhaust doesn't make it out, but I wonder if you could try different way of getting mass out of a very deep gravity well. Shouldn't be too hard. Even if it was only a little bit, we could always just scale it up...

Comment: Try making your answer less verbose and heavier on facts. As written, it doesn't answer the question either.

Comment: @OrganicMarble thank's for your interest (and down-vote). To start with not answering the question: you're right I didn't give a hard answer. The problem is this is really a grey area. How big really just equates to how many issues are you're willing to magic away. My answer really only says unless your willing to ignore conservation of mass, 5 times as big will be a problem. I think that's interesting.

Comment: @OrganicMarble To answer your "being heavy lowers exhaust velocity,  not making  sense" comment sorry, perhaps I explained it badly. Maybe this image would help. Imagine throwing a ball tethered to your hand by a strand of elastic. How thick the elastic is will effect how much momentum you can _ultimately_ put into it for a given throw.

Comment: I can't see how this is an answer to the question, or even supplements other answers. This reads like a conversation or a blogpost. Can you add a tl;dr at the beginning summarizing the key points of your answer? The conversational approach doesn't really fit the Stack Exchange Question/Answer format.

Answer (score -2):

On a practical engineering side of things.  Ultimately you are limited by exhaust velocity.  In theory you can always just make a bigger engine, bigger tanks, etc.  Ridiculously expensive, but possible.  This would seem to set the real limit to material strength.  Material strength is likely to give out before the gravity wells pull exceeds the exhaust velocity of even moderately modern fuels.

For example, LF+LOX typically has an exhaust velocity of around 4,400 m/s.  Which will fight up to 448 G of gravity.  Literally more than the sun.  Practically however much less than that.  So size of the planet itself presents no real deal killers, it just makes  the payloads mass fraction very VERY low.

At some point though other technologies, like nuclear bomb drives (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)), become the only feasible affordable way off the planet.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are connecting exhaust velocity with "fighting gravity". It is true that a rocket with an exhaust velocity of 4400 m/s could only lift about 1 seconds worth of fuel supply against 448g, but that's not really directly relevant. You need to use the rocket equation and formulae for the escape or orbital velocities of planets of various sizes and densities to get a sensible answer.

Comment: A real rocket will never get close to the 1 second point.  Payload for this calculation includes the engine and fuel tanks as well, which will always have nonzero mass.  the 448 G's is literally the point where the fuel cant even lift itself off the ground.  That is a jet of exhaust moving at that velocity would not even be able to escape the engine if pointed straight up., let alone lift any additional fuel