# Maturity of interplanetary rockets technology with known fuel supply is close?

Tags: rockets, engineering

Considerably, the scale of current jet propulsion rocket technology to leave Earth is closely connected to the target delivery mass, mission goal and the required fuel quantity to lift and deliver this cargo.

So even BFR based cargo concepts already include refueling concept.

Could be there a mission worth building even larger rockets than BFR/Saturn and that would still make sense? Or is this scale more or less the end of how big propulsion rockets will ever be?

[BFR as compared to large buildings and other objects](https://www.businessinsider.de/spacex-big-falcon-rocket-size-comparison-elon-musk-2018-10?r=US&IR=T)

Comment: Possibly related: [Is there a theoretical limit to the size of launch vehicles?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23389/12978)