# How much higher could g be before we couldn't launch rockets?

Tags: launch, rockets, gravity, rocket-equation

Obviously having a higher gravitational acceleration makes it harder to get rockets into orbit / escape.

How much stronger could earths gravity be before we would no longer be able to do the sort of launches we do today (probes to deep space, people to leo, etc.) with out current technology?

Alternatively, what would most powerful rockets be able to do if earths gravity was twice as strong?

Comment: It's a great question! However it's been asked and answered before. [How much bigger could Earth be, before rockets would't work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14383/12102) *Welcome to Space!* Don't worry if your question is closed, but you can consider modifying your question to make it sufficiently different from the linked question so that a different answer would be necessary.