Why, if gravity were higher, would designing a fully reusable rocket be impossible?
I was watching this video:
Elon Musk, 13 years ago: A fully and rapidly reusable rocket is barely possible
And Elon Musk says,

.. a fully and rapidly reusable orbit-class rocket. This is a very
difficult thing to do, because we live on a planet where that is just
barely possible. If gravity were a little lower it would be easy, if
it was a little higher it would be impossible

What is the cause?

This is probably a duplicate of https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14383/6944

FYI: currently a falcon9 launch is roughly in price with a non-reusable soyuz launch. Thus, the fully reusable rocket is still not a reached goal, particularly that falcon9 is not fully reusable (ok, mostly reusable). It might be better in the future, but that is not now, yet.

Astronaut Don Pettit's original 2012 essay "The Tyranny of the Rocket Equation" is no longer available at its original location on the NASA website, but here is an archived version I recognize the link from the mipselling of the word "tryanny" in the URL. His talk of the same title can be found hosted on several YouTube channels as well.

I found the link here in Reddit and I find the comment below it also interesting; "Reminds me of the short story "The Cold Equations."

I've undeleted In what event (video) did Elon Musk start saying "...if Earth were a little heavier..." and then backtrack? temporarily in case it has something helpful here. It's a different question - I'm asking about "I also remember seeing Elon Musk mention this supposed limit, something like 'If Earth were a little heavier... conventional rockets wouldn't work...' then catch himself and say something like 'wait - is that right?'"

There's a pretty strong correlation between gravity and the delta-v that you need to get to orbit, so mathematically, what he's saying is that...
$$\exp{\left({{\Delta}V-\text{a little} \over V_\mathrm{Exhaust}}\right)} <<< \exp{\left({{\Delta}V \over V_\mathrm{Exhaust}}\right)} <<< \exp{\left({{\Delta}V+\text{a little} \over V_\mathrm{Exhaust}}\right)}$$
If we plug in some typical numbers, such as 9.5 km/s for ${\Delta}V$, 2 km/s for '$\text{a little}$', and 3 km/s for $V_\mathrm{Exhaust}$, we get
$$12.1 <<< 23.7 <<< 46.2$$
You can see that decreasing the delta-v by roughly 20% almost halved the calculated value whereas increasing the delta-v by 20% almost doubled the calculated value. What we're witnessing here is simply the exponential behavior of the rocket equation.
Now recall that
$${m_0 \over m_f} = \exp{\left({{\Delta}V \over V_\mathrm{Exhaust}}\right)}$$
In a single stage rocket, $m_f$ is the mass of everything on the pad except for the propellent that you consume on the way up. Most importantly, $m_f$ has to be large enough to allow you to build a machine that can lift $m_0$ off the pad.
So, in this illustrative example, "It would be easy" equates to building a rocket that can lift 12 times its own mass.
"It would be impossible" equates to building a rocket that can lift 46 times it's own mass.
With a two-stage rocket, these ratios are smaller. But, if you want to leave room for payload, then the ratios become bigger.
It's the rocket equivalent of someone saying,

If I had four arms, it would be easy to do ten pullups. But if I had only one arm, then it would be almost impossible.

Now, to quote Wernher Von Braun

I have learned to use the word 'impossible' with the greatest caution.


I've suggested an edit to fix it, but please use \text{} or \mathrm{} when writing text in math mode (pedantically, \text is for text and \mathrm is for upright letters in maths, so they do slightly different things with spaces etc). Subscripts should only be italic when the subscript alone would be italic, eg $v_x$ for $x$-velocity

It is also important to realize that it is very hard to reach orbit even with disposable rockets. In excess of 90% of the mass of a chemical rocket has to consist of propellant to get to orbit and most of the remaining 10% is the huge tank to hold the propellants, the engines and other structural elements leaving just a few percent at best for payload. That’s why orbital rockets tend to be large. Making a rocket reusable makes things even harder as it involves additional heavy equipment such as landing legs, parachutes, heat shields, flaps etc that take up payload capability.
Elon Musk was taking about reusable chemical rockets which are already operating towards the top end of what is possible. But it would require detailed calculations to find where the limit actually is and that would depend on assumptions about exhaust velocities, practicalities of the number of possible stages and the size of the payload, engine efficiencies etc. Using nuclear engines would make matters easier but at the cost of having a nuclear reactor flying in the atmosphere.
Perhaps the biggest difficulty is for the layman to appreciate the tyranny of exponential functions. As an example say that a 1 ton payload can be accelerated to 1000mph by 1 ton of propellant. How much propellant would be needed to accelerate the the payload to 2000mph? The obvious simplistic answer of 2 tons is wrong. And its wrong because that extra 1 ton of propellant would also need to be accelerated to 1000mph first (just like the payload) before it can then be use to accelerate the payload from 1000mph to 2000mph, so 3 tons would be needed (and 7 tons to reach 3000mph and 15 tons to reach 4000mph etc)
Note this is a very crude example only to illustrate the nature of the exponential effect of the rocket equation (so yes I know...).

Just to expand on this: Starship is, by many measures, very much not an elegant design. It is a brutal bully, beating the laws of physics into submission by sheer brute force. But, that seems to be what is needed to make a launch system fully and rapidly reusable. With only slightly higher gravity, this brute force approach would no longer work.
